# LibGDX pause image in game

Tags: java, android, libgdx

i am new to libgdx and i have tried several ways to adding pause function and image.  Can anyone correct my mistakes? i am stuck

```
package com.badlogic.drop;

import java.util.Iterator;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;

public class GameScreen implements Screen {
final Drop game;

Texture dropImage;
Texture bucketImage;
Texture pauseImage;
Sound dropSound;
Music rainMusic;
OrthographicCamera camera;
Rectangle bucket;
Rectangle pause;
Array<Rectangle> raindrops;
long lastDropTime;
int dropsGathered;

public GameScreen(final Drop gam) {
    this.game = gam;

    // load the images for the droplet and the bucket, 64x64 pixels each
    dropImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("droplet.png"));
    bucketImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bucket.png"));
    pauseImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("pause.png"));
    // load the drop sound effect and the rain background "music"
    dropSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("drop.wav"));
    rainMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("rain.mp3"));
    rainMusic.setLooping(true);

    // create the camera and the SpriteBatch
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);

    // create a Rectangle to logically represent the bucket
    bucket = new Rectangle();
    bucket.x = 800 / 2 - 64 / 2; // center the bucket horizontally
    bucket.y = 20; // bottom left corner of the bucket is 20 pixels above
    // the bottom screen edge
    bucket.width = 64;
    bucket.height = 64;

    pause = new Rectangle();
    pause.x =700;
    pause.y =380;
    pause.width = 64;
    pause.height = 64;

    // create the raindrops array and spawn the first raindrop
    raindrops = new Array<Rectangle>();
    spawnRaindrop();
}

private void spawnRaindrop() {
    Rectangle raindrop = new Rectangle();
    raindrop.x = MathUtils.random(0, 800 - 64);
    raindrop.y = 480;
    raindrop.width = 64;
    raindrop.height = 64;
    raindrops.add(raindrop);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

public enum State{Running,Paused}
State state = State.Running;
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    switch(state) {
        case Running:
            update();
            break;
        case Paused:
            Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
            break;
    }
    draw();
}
public void update(){
    Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();
}
public void draw(){// clear the screen with a dark blue color. The
    // arguments to glClearColor are the red, green
    // blue and alpha component in the range [0,1]
    // of the color to be used to clear the screen.
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // tell the camera to update its matrices.
    camera.update();

    // tell the SpriteBatch to render in the
    // coordinate system specified by the camera.
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    // begin a new batch and draw the bucket and
    // all drops
    game.batch.begin();
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "Drops Collected: " + dropsGathered, 0, 480);
    game.batch.draw(bucketImage, bucket.x, bucket.y);
    game.batch.draw(pauseImage, pause.x, pause.y);
    for (Rectangle raindrop : raindrops) {
        game.batch.draw(dropImage, raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
    }
    game.batch.end();
```

How to code the button into game`

```
    // process user input
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
        touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        camera.unproject(touchPos);
        bucket.x = touchPos.x - 64 / 2;
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT))
        bucket.x -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT))
        bucket.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    // make sure the bucket stays within the screen bounds
    if (bucket.x < 0)
        bucket.x = 0;
    if (bucket.x > 800 - 64)
        bucket.x = 800 - 64;

    // check if we need to create a new raindrop
    if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000)
        spawnRaindrop();

    // move the raindrops, remove any that are beneath the bottom edge of
    // the screen or that hit the bucket. In the later case we play back
    // a sound effect as well.
    Iterator<Rectangle> iter = raindrops.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Rectangle raindrop = iter.next();
        raindrop.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (raindrop.y + 64 < 0)
            iter.remove();
        if (raindrop.overlaps(bucket)) {
            dropsGathered++;
            dropSound.play();
            iter.remove();
        }
    }}   

@Override
public void hide() {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}
```

CRY

Comment: i am new to stack over flow too....

Answer (score 0):

There are several improvements to be made.

### Pausing the game

It is common practise to create a new method called `update`, where you can dump all logic inside of (like moving the textures). You call this method from your `render` loop.
If you wouldn't call this method if the game is paused.

I see you've already done this. You do not need to call any of those `setContinuousRendering` methods. Your statemachine should work. You could also opt to just use a boolean (`isPaused` for example).

I haven't seen a method to set the state to Paused, so I don't know how you want to test your pause system.
You'll have to make a button or use console input or just pause immediately to test it.

### Sprites

I recommend you use Sprites instead of manually creating rectangles with textures, it makes your life a lot easier.
Sprites are basically textures + rectangles and some rendering code.

### Performance

I would call `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()` once, then save the return value inside a variable. This way the method doesn't get called for everything you need the value for.

You use `TimeUtils.nanoTime()`. I personally use Java's `System.currentTimeMillis()`, since it is a 100x higher value. This way you don't have to type all those zeroes.

The render method gets called automatically because you are using Scene2D. It has a parameter called delta. You can use this variable instead of manually making one.
Just change your `update()` method to `update(float delta)` and pass the variable.

In your `draw` method, you update the camera. If you don't move the camera, this is redundant.

Good luck with your game!

**Edit**: I misread your question. You can use Scene2D to create a button. This button will fire an event you can use to set the Paused state.
You are creating your game inside of a Screen, you should use a Stage instead. Look up some more about Scene2D.

**Edit 2**: Formatting